# running linux executables from linux shell scripts

Tags: shell

I want to run a executable from my shell script. The executable is located at /usr/bin/to_run.

My shell script(which is calling the above executable) is in the /usr/bin folder.

The shell script is :

```
#!/bin/bash

#kill all existing instances of synergy

killall synergys
sh "/usr/bin/synergys"

if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
echo "synergy server started"
else
echo "error in starting"
fi
```

I am getting an error saying : "synergys : no process found".

When I run the same thing - /usr/bin/synergys directly from the terminal it runs fine, but from within a script there are problems. I don't understand why.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error is from the `killall` command, it's saying there are no candidate processes matching your argument.

If you don't want to be notified where no processes match, just use the `quiet` option:

```
killall -q synergys
```

From the `killall` man page:

> **-q, --quiet**
>        Do not complain if no processes were killed.

Comment: I also wanted a recommendation. In situations like mine, is it better to make alias or write full fledged scripts ?

Comment: @user590849, I tend to prefer scripts (or shell functions) for anything more complicated than a one-liner. In addition, because aliases are just word substitutions, you can't put arguments in there like `alias fls=find . -name $1 | less` - it's only good for commands where the arguments come at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If `/usr/bin/synergys` is an executable and not a shell script, you will run it directly, not via the shell:

```
/usr/bin/synergys
```

Or, since `/usr/bin` is on the `$PATH` of most people, you could simply write:

```
synergys
```

If `/usr/bin/synergys` is actually a shell script, it should be executable (for example, 555 or `-r-xr-xr-x` permissions), and you can still write just `synergys` to execute it.  You only need to use an explicit `sh` if the file `/usr/bin/synergys` is not executable *and* is a shell script.